# how to show form input in a sentence on screen at input

Tags: javascript

I have a multi-tab form and would like to put the input of all fields in one sentence at input.
Tried many ways but I can not find any code that works.

So the form asks for: Name, how many children (out of buttons), what date, and some other things.
I want it to show "Hi *name* you have *number* children and want a reservation on *date*" for example.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You wrote _"Tried many ways but I can not find any code that works."_ Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67542933/edit) to show us the code you tried. We are not a code writing service, but we can help you with the code you have written. Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for that like ...

    `console.log(\`Hi ${name} you have ${number} children and want a reservation on ${date}.\`)`

Comment: please show us the code you tried and what you have done